# if no item of a combobox is selected do semothing in Java Fx

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I am using JavaFX have a list of items in a combobox , when  a user trys to register i want that a condition cheks if he selected an item or not in that combo. i have tryed this but it doesent work , how to do it please .

```
public void ADDuser(ActionEvent event) {
    String username = usernametf.getText();
    String pass = passtf.getText();
    LocalDate datebirth = dateofbirth.getValue();
    String situation = situationcombobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (!username.equals("") &&
        !pass.equals("") &&
        !datebirth.equals(null) &&
        !situation.equals(null)) {// situaion problem
            mainc.con.AdduserDatabase(username, pass, datebirth, situation, gender);        
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Information Ajout");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Ajout réussi merci " );
            alert.showAndWait();
            Stage stage = (Stage) btnadd.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println(situation);
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Information Ajout");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Please Fill All the fields ! " );
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What actually happens?

Comment: You will get NPE in `situationcombobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString()` if nothing is selected, since `getSelectedItem()` will return null.

Comment: ah ok , then what i should do , to get that the user havent chose an item from the combo list to display an error message ?

Comment: Test to see if `selectedItem` is null, instead of assuming you can convert it to a string and testing if the string is empty.

Comment: thanks a lot a solved it, the proper way is to test is it empty or not like this       !situationcombobox.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()      then get the value from it into a variable                                                                  situation = situationcombobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();